# Randomly select a percentage of columns and rows in a dataframe (Pandas, Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to randomly select a certain percentage of rows and columns in my dataframe and fit these features into a logistic regression over 10 iterations.  My dependent variable is whether a team won (1) or lost (0).

If I have a df that looks something like this (data is made up):

```
 Won    Field    Injuries   Weather    Fouls    Players
  1       2         3         1          2         8
  0       3         2         0          1         5
  1       4         5         3          2         6
  1       3         2         1          4         5 
  0       2         3         0          1         6
  1       4         2         0          2         8
  ...
```

For example, let's say I want to select 50% (but this could change). I want to randomly select 50% (or the closest amount to 50% if its an odd number) of the columns (field,injuries,weather,fouls,players) and 50% of the rows in those columns to place in my model.

Here is my current code which right now runs by selecting **all** of the columns and rows and fitting it into my model but I would like to dictate a random percentage:

```
z = []
For i in range(10):
    train_cols = df.columns[1:] 
    logit = sm.Logit(df['Won'], df[train_cols])
    result = logit.fit()
    exp = np.exp(result.params)
    z.append([i, exp])
```

Comment: Hi Andy Hayden -- I see the overlap in these questions so I appreciate the reference.  One quick point: my question also deals with taking random columns and not just the entire data frame

Comment: Generate indicies with np.random.choice(np.arange(m), (k*m,), replace=False) Where m - number of features/samples, m - number in range [0,1],   e.g. for 50% - 0.5.

Comment: Hi Olologin -- thank you for your feedback!  I actually figured out the answer which is why I would like to reopen this question and post how to randomly select BOTH rows and columns :)

Comment: @user3682157, I think the question is open now, you can post your answer.